# ServiceStack Self-Hosted app and NotifyIcon

Tags: servicestack, notifyicon

I have a working Windows Service (on Windows 10, .Net471) that implements ServiceStack AppSelfHost Base and provides a number of (so far) simple REST APIs. I'd like to add NotifyIcon type of functionality, so that the service displays an icon in the Windows Notification Area for all users on the machine, and right-clicking that icon displays a context menu of actions. I've tried implementing the NotifyIcon WinForms component in the AppHost.Configure method, naively following the instructions here [NotifyIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon(v=vs.110).aspx). This naive implementation does not work; when the System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run() is called, the NotifyIcon functionality works, but the .Run() call (in AppHost.Configure) does not return, and then no ServiceStack REST APIs work; if I comment out the call to .Run(), the ServiceStack code works, but NotifyIcon functionality does not. Can anyone please point me towards links or examples that show a self-hosted ServiceStack implementation that provides an icon in the Windows Notification area, and a context menu of functions that appear when the icon is right-clicked? TIA!